# Check validates_uniqueness_of in rails for two values in or condtion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, activemodel, validates-uniqueness-of

i'm having problem in checking validates_uniqueness_of which has two condtion.

Class name is InviteGuest

```
class InviteGuest < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :invite_id, :email, :first_name, :last_name, :random_no

  validates_presence_of :invite_id, :unless => :random_no?

  validates_uniqueness_of :email, :scope => [:invite_id]
```

Here i'm checking `invite_id` or `:random` number for presence. 
so here my `:email` feilds are entering first with unique  `:random_no` .which works fine.and i;m `validates_uniqueness_of :email, :scope => [:invite_id]` but it's not allowing me to enter  same `:email` for different `:random_no`. i have to put or condition. it's cheking for `:invite_id` but i would like to check it for `:random_no` if `:invite_id` is not present. but it's not allowing me to enter `:email` for different `:random_no`.

Any idea??

Comment: That was quite hard to follow, could you add some more context about what you're goal is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to like your scope is not set correctly. You should scope on `random_no`:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :email, scope: [:invite_id, :random_no]
```

Comment: but dosent that one will check unique email for both values i mean AND relation??
i would like to check for invite_id if present, and if not then check for random_no for restricting same email. but above code not allowing me to check unique email for invite_id which is very staight forward code.
But i'm confuse at
 validates_presence_of :invite_id, :unless => :random_no?
Dose this code automitcaly check for :random_no if :invite_id is nor present?? because its not. It's giving me validation error coz there is no :invite_id and same same :email is trying to insert with diff :random_no.